# Как сделать округление, в layer-list?

Tags: android, xml, style

То есть мне нужно поставить картинку на `button`, установить цвет и округлость.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_location" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только получается совсем не то, что нужно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это вам такая картинка нужна?

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, вопрос был не в этом

Comment: ну, с цветом и кнопкой вроде понятно, но что вы округлять хотите? Она же круглая))

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, это стиль для кнопки, кнопку нужно округлить, хотя в заголовке, как раз и написано, что для кнопки все

Comment: Ответ в другом посте
[Как сделать кнопку как на картинке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863147/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5)