# Как сделать кнопку как на картинке?

Tags: android, button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать маленький размер картинки на белом фоне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наконец-то решил

shape_button_location.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="9dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

layer_button_location.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_button_location" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_location"
         android:top="10dp"
         android:bottom="10dp"
         android:left="10dp"
         android:right="10dp">
     </item>
 </layer-list>
```

И сам `button`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMap"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layer_button_location"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]